# Question about approximating an area based on a graph

Tags: area

Here is the question and image:
[image]

Hi,
here is my attempt:

Each block has an area of $(1/2)^2 = 1/4$ miles$^2$.  This grey region covers $14$ blocks. So $14*1/4 = 3.5$. So the approximate area is $3.5$. However, the answer is $2.75$ miles. I do not know why the answer is $2.75$. Thanks!

Comment: Notice that your approximation differs from the answer of 2.75 square miles only by an error of 0.75 square miles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps have a recount - there are approximately 11 shaded squares (give or take). You are right in that each square is $0.25$ miles$^2$. $0.25$ miles$^2$ x $11$ gives $2.75$ square miles.

Remember it's an estimate, so the answer closest to yours would still be  $2.75$ square miles.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation is not precise. Your approximation is $3.5$, but you count blocks that aren't fully covered either.

So you know that your approximation is a bit too high, and 2.75 square miles is the answer closest to your approximation.